# Problem on ip_address value in code igniter 4 session

Tags: php, session, codeigniter-4

I have created table to store session handler, but why value of ip_address field always ::1, is it because my project still in localhost? is it suppose to be my ip address? Thank you

[image]

My session config :

```
public $sessionDriver            = 'CodeIgniter\Session\Handlers\DatabaseHandler';
public $sessionCookieName        = 'ci_session';
public $sessionExpiration        = 7200;
public $sessionSavePath          = 'session';
public $sessionMatchIP           = true;
public $sessionTimeToUpdate      = 300;
public $sessionRegenerateDestroy = false;
```

Comment: `::1` is the IPV6 value which is the same as localhost (or 127.0.0.1).

Comment: so if i upload my project to server, value of ip_address field will be my server ip? not client ip?

Answer (score 0):

ip_address is retrieved from $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']. So it is IP address of client.

Codeigniter 4 reference:
https://codeigniter4.github.io/CodeIgniter4/libraries/sessions.html#accessing-session-metadata